# I cannot established connection with WCF services in Xamarin

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wcf-binding

I have a WPF application in VB.NET that already developed by my old colleagues. Now, my superior want to replace current platform by implementing the same concept to be run on the Android system. So, I've decided to use Xamarin Android .NET Standard.

I have searched for a way to consume WCF and the error throw before I'm asking but I'm still stuck at the same error.

I have set up the service references WCF on the android class. Given on solution, I have 2 projects:- **MyProject** and **MyProject.Android**

===========================================================================

**WPF**

```
Private Function EstablishConnect() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim context As InstanceContext = New InstanceContext(Me)
        svrobj = New DisplayServicesClient(context, "DisplayTcpBinding")
        Dim endpointAddress As New EndpointAddress(modUtility.ServerEndPointAddress)
        svrobj.Endpoint.Address = endpointAddress
        svrobj.Open()
        SecondDiffFromServer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Now, svrobj.GetDateTime)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog.Log(ex.ToString, True)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

modUtility.ServerEndPointAddress get from INI:

> net.tcp://localhost:8002/AppServ/WCFServices/Display

===========================================================================

**XAMARIN FORMS**

```
private async Task<bool> EstablishConnectAsync()
{
    try
    {
        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
        svrobj = new DisplayServicesClient(DisplayServicesClientBase.EndpointConfiguration.DisplayTcpBinding); //, DisplayServicesClientBase.EndpointConfiguration.DisplayTcpBinding
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(modUtility.ServerEndPointAddress);
        svrobj.Endpoint.Address = endpointAddress;
        await svrobj.OpenAsync();
        modUtility.SecondDiffFromServer = (int)(DateTime.Now - await svrobj.GetDateTimeAsync()).TotalSeconds;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ResultText.Text = "Unable to established connection with endpoint service. Ex-" + ex.Message;
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

modUtility.ServerEndPointAddress get from settings:

> net.tcp://10.0.2.2:8002/AppServ/WCFServices/Display

I'm currently run android on emulator.

My code throw exception on any call to `svrobj` function. Below are the error that throw:-

1. > The communication object System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1[AppServ.IDisplayServices] is not at created state but at Opening state.
2. > The method or operation is not implemented.

Do I missing something or do I have implement wrong way?

Comment: i think [restful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest) services consumed with HTTPClient is a far far better approach,if you want use wcf in xamarin.forms,you may refer to [wcf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT my direction currently is open to use anything that works not to keep on WCF. Currently, our WCF can established a connection and client will wait for any command from web service without keep requesting. I'm not sure, but restful can do like that? Meaning, established connection and wait for command without keep POST/GET to web service at certain interval.

Comment: restful could not keep requesting as you said,maybe you could refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44976/xamarin-with-wcf-complete-example, there is a example for using WCF in Xamarin.Forms.